# Crear ventana modal a partir de una tabla

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, modal

La idea es que al hacer clic sobre el boton que está al final de cada renglón en la tabla, abra una ventana modal mostrando la información de las personas.
El problema que se me está presentando es que sólo obtiene la información del primer registro de la tabla

El blade:

```
@extends('persona.layouts.layout')

@section('content')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 ml-auto">
    <h1>
        {{ Form::open (['route' => 'persona.index', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'form-inline pull-right']) }}
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::text('nombre', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Nombre']) }}                  
        </div>
        &nbsp
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::text('empresa', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Empresa']) }}                  
        </div>
        &nbsp
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Buscar contacto</button>
         {{Form::close()}}
    </h1>            
</div>



<div class="col-md-12">             
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
    <thead>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Empresa</th>
        <th>Telefono</th>
        <th>Celular</th>
        <th>Correo electrónico</th>

        <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>        
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @if(count($personas))
        @foreach($personas as $persona)
        <tr>
            <td> {{$persona->nombre}}</td>
            <td> {{$persona->apellido}}</td>
            <td>{{$persona->empresa}}</td>
            <td>{{$persona->telefono}}</td>
            <td>{{$persona->celular}}</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:{{$persona->correo}}">{{$persona->correo}}</a></td>
            <td align="center">
                <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
                <a href="{{route('persona.show', $persona)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-xl" title="Ver" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForm"> Ver</a>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">           
                            <p class="statusMsg"></p>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <h2 class="headertekst">{{$persona->nombre .' ' . $persona->apellido}}</h2>
                                        <hr>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 field-label-responsive"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">       
                                        @if (($persona->empresa=='Lafedar')||($persona->empresa=='lafedar'))
                                            <p> <strong>Interno: </strong>{{$persona->interno}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Area: </strong>{{$persona->area}}</p>
                                            <p><strong>Puesto: </strong>{{$persona->puesto}}</p>
                                        @endif
                                        <p><strong>Empresa: </strong>{{$persona->empresa}}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Direccion: </strong>{{$persona->direccion}}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Celular: </strong>{{$persona->celular}}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Teléfono: </strong>{{$persona->telefono}}</p>
                                        <p><strong>Correo: </strong>{{$persona->correo}}</p>         
                                        <!-- Modal Footer -->
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                                &nbsp
                                                <a class="btn-info btn"  href="{{route('persona.edit', $persona->id)}}">Editar</a>
                                                &nbsp
                                                <form action="{{route('persona.destroy', $persona->id)}}" onclick="return confirm ('Está seguro que desea eliminar?')" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                                                    {{ method_field('DELETE')}} 
                                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger ">Borrar</button> 
                                                </form>
                                            </div>         
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>   
           </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        @endif  
    </tbody>       
 </table>
{{ $personas->appends($_GET)->links() }}
</div>

@stop
```

Como se puede apreciar; tanto el botón como el modal están dentro del foreach.

En un principio el modal era un archivo aparte "show.blade.php" pero de esta forma no abría la ventana modal.

Les agradecería cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme. Me gustaría aprender como es la lógica para crear ventanas modales ya que quedan muy bien en las vistas

A disposición si necesitan más información

Comment: Juan, puede que le interese leer esto [tour], y te recomiendo leer [ask] para orientarte en como formular una pregúnta. Necesitas publicar el código que tienes hasta ahora para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola que tal, si nos muestras algo de tu código podemos llegar mas rápido a la solucion! Saludos

Comment: Buenas, disculpen la demora. Agradezco su tiempo. Edité la consulta para que sea más clara, agregando el código correspondiente

Comment: Hola Juan bienvenido a SO español. Entonces tu problema es que esta vista solo te muestra la primera persona (el primer registro), no?

Comment: Hola! Sí, el problema es que siempre me muestra el primer registro.

Comment: Vale, de antemano yo también llevo poco con Laravel, que yo entienda debería de tener un controlador EmpleadoController por ejemplo o como le hayas llamado tu donde recojes todos los empleados y se los pasas a la vista en cuestión, el blade que muestras que nose que nombre tiene. no?

Comment: Yo suelo tener un Modelo el cual se conecta a la tabla y luego en el controlador le hago: 1) use App\NombreModelo, 2)$empleados = NombreModelo::all()
Y luego le haces el return al blade en cuestión pasandole como parametro  $empleados. (Los nombres me los he inventado)

Comment: @HelloThere Si, eso está implementado. Hay un controlador que busca los registros de la BD y los envia a la vista en un array.

Comment: En la vista, recorro ese array completando la tabla. Ahora bien, cuando quiero hacer un SHOW donde me muestre muestre en una ventana modal la información de cierto registro solo me trae el primero. Osea, la primer iteración del foreach

Comment: Igual es una tontería pero te estas asegurando que en la empresa Lafedar o lafedar tenga más de un registro?